# Using numpy.histogram on an array of images

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate image histograms of an numpy array of images. The array of images is of shape `(n_images, width, height, colour_channels)` and I want to return an array of shape `(n_images, count_in_each_bin (i.e. 255))`. This is done via two intermediary steps of averaging each colour channel for each image and then flattening each 2D image to a 1D one.

I think have successfully done this with the code below, however I have cheated a bit with the for loop at the end. My question is this - is there a way of getting rid of the last for loop and using an optimised numpy function instead?

```
def histogram_helper(flattened_image: np.array) -> np.array:
    counts, _ = np.histogram(flattened_image, bins=[n for n in range(0, 256)])
    return counts

# Using 10 RGB images of width and height 300
images = np.zeros((10, 300, 300, 3))

# Take the mean of the three colour channels
channel_avg = np.mean(images, axis=3)

# Flatten each image in the array of images, resulting in a 1D representation of each image.
flat_images = channel_avg.reshape(*channel_avg.shape[:-2], -1)

# Now calculate the counts in each of the colour bins for each image in the array.
# This will provide us with a count of how many times each colour appears in an image.
result = np.empty((0, len(self.histogram_bins) - 1), dtype=np.int32)
for image in flat_images:
    colour_counts = self.histogram_helper(image)
    colour_counts = colour_counts.reshape(1, -1)
    result = np.concatenate([result, colour_counts])
```

Comment: `[n for n in range(0, 256)]` -> `list(range(256))`, or better yet, `np.arange(256)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to call `np.histogram` or `np.bincount` for this, since pixel values are in the range `0` to `N`. That means that you can treat them as indices and simply use a counter.

Here's how I would transform the initial images, which I imaging are of dtype `np.uint8`:

```
images = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 5, 5, 3))  # 10 5x5 images, 3 channels
reshaped = np.round(images.reshape(images.shape[0], -1, images.shape[-1]).mean(-1)).astype(images.dtype)
```

Now you can simply count the histograms using unbuffered addition with `np.add.at`:

```
result = np.zeros((images.shape[0], 256), int)
index = np.arange(len(images))[:, None]
np.add.at(result, (index, reshaped), 1)
```

The last operation is in-place and therefore returns `None`, but the answer will be in `result` nevertheless.

Comment: Having tried to run this I find that the final addition returns `None`.

Comment: It shouldn't. np.add.at should return the output array. I was able to test this successfully. What's different about how you're using this?

Comment: Nothing I copied and pasted it straight into a Python console.

>>> images = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 5, 5, 3))

>>> reshaped = np.round(images.reshape(images.shape[0], -1, images.shape[-1]).mean(-1)).astype(images.dtype)

>>> output = np.zeros((images.shape[0], 256), int)

>>> index = np.arange(len(images))[:, None]

>>> result = np.add.at(output, (index, reshaped), 1)

>>> result == None

True

Comment: Sorry format looks a mess

Comment: @Tom111989. Gotcha. `output` is the result. The operation is in-place, so you're right that the function returns `None`

Comment: @Tom111989. I changed the name of the variable and added a note at the end of the question.